# translate configuration

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.2

I put my site general settings (sitename and title) in a configuration file, and load it in `bootstrap.php` by `Configure::load('config')`.

Because my site is bilingual, I decided to go with I8n class. So in `config.php` I use `__()` function to translate site title:

```
$config = array(
    'title' => __('SITE TITLE')
);
```

for default language, it works fine (and shows "SITE TITLE"), because I put `Configure::write('Config.language', 'eng');` right before `load` function. But for other languages, it doesn't work; and shows title in English (default lang.)

I get new language from URL, and set it as new (default) language in `AppController` `beforeFilter` method. (You know, controllers will load after bootstrap.)

What do you suggest I do? (without using a database table for getting/setting site general setting)

Comment: why not translating later in the application? or "on demand" on output?

Comment: @mark: what do you mean? using `TranslateBehavior`?

Comment: in your appcontroller beforeRender() for example, or on output in the view/element/layout `echo __($translateMe);`